# Invalid type for argument in function call, implicit conversion from uint256 to string memory requested

Tags: solidity, truffle, transactions

I’m working on a transaction smart contract and I was pushing my Struct into the transaction array but while inputing the details i got the above error.

Comment: Please, share the code that causes the error.

Comment: https://github.com/joeephwild/Venmo-blockchain
That’s the code

Comment: I download the project, the contract compiles just fine without errors. The frontend doesn't cause any error related to blockchain.